# Regenerating entity objects via EDMGEN in an MSBUILD project

Tags: entity-framework, msbuild

I have my build executing edmgen successfully however it's generating entity objects for all of my database tables.  What I'd like to have it do is only generate for select tables like it currently does in the project locally.

I'm using full generation and passing in a connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to work with a subset of objects in EDMGen. You can try creating a new schema containing only the necessary tables, and run EDMGen for this schema only.

Comment: Arranged my tables into seperate schemas but I can figure out how to run EDMGen for a specified schema

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create your own version of EdmGen by using the [EdmGen2 code base](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2).

In the ModelGen method you can define EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry filters to select which tables you want.